# add and remove class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

how can I add a class on the second element when I click on the first one and remove it when I click on the second element.

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="element1">
  <input type="radio" class="element2">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" class="element1">
  <input type="radio" class="element2">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" class="element1">
  <input type="radio" class="element2">
</div>
```

I tied this code but is not working properly, add and remove the class in all div

```
$('.element1').on('click',function(){
   $('.element2').addClass('active');

});
$('.element2').on('click',function(){
   $('.element2').removeClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Thank you for adding your coding attempt. Please see my answer below. You're coding logic is flawed and behaves as it should. By saying `$('.element2').addClass('active');` You are telling JQuery to apply that `className` to all elements with `className` `element2`. My answer shows how to only apply the `className` to `siblings` of the element with `className` `element1` which is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//On DOM ready, add click event handlers to elements with className element1
//When element1 is clicked, it gets all siblings with className element2 and adds the className you want
//Adds event handler for click on elements with className element2 and removes the className
//This solution is done using JQuery
$(function(){
    $('.element1').on('click', function(){
        $(this).siblings('.element2').addClass('active');
    });

    $('.element2').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a little bit of javascript or use a library as jQuery, I don't clearly understand your answer so I hope this can help you.

```js
function add_class() {
  document.getElementById('element2').setAttribute("class", "style_button new_style");
}

function remove_class() {
  //document.getElementById('element1').removeAttribute("class");
  document.getElementById('element2').setAttribute("class", "style_button");
}
```

```css
.style_button {
  width: 64px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #f7e33e;
}

.new_style {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="element1" type="button" class="style_button" onclick="add_class()" value="Add">
  <input id="element2" type="button" class="style_button" onclick="remove_class()" value="Remove">
</div>
```

For more informatión you can visit https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: This will not solve the question. The OP's question wants to know how to change the class on the sibling element with className .element2. Using inline event handlers is also frowned upon in today's programming world, so I wouldn't be advising that either.